# C# | Buttons under Format section not working

Tags: c#

I have a question!

I'm currently making a notepad app and everything was going well until now.

The way it's set up:
There's a panel with the menu buttons (File, Edit, Themes, & Format) and a panel at the bottom with all of the options under each tab. Both the menu button and sub-buttons are labels.
When you click a menu button, the bottom panel will show the buttons categorized under that section by making all labels there invisible, and then making the appropriate ones visible.

Everything seems to work fine except for the 2 buttons under Format (Font & Font Color). They show up, but do not do anything when clicked. Below is the code for it.

```cs
private void FontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
    if(fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.Font = fd.Font;
    }
}

private void FontColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();

    if(cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = cd.Color;
    }
}

private void Label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Config();

    FontButton.Visible = true;
    FontColor.Visible = true;
}

private void Config()
{
    New.Visible = false;
    Open.Visible = false;
    Save.Visible = false;
    Light.Visible = false;
    Dark.Visible = false;
    FontButton.Visible = false;
    FontColor.Visible = false;
    Undo.Visible = false;
    Cut.Visible = false;
    Copy.Visible = false;
    Paste.Visible = false;
}
```

Is the code wrong? Is it because the labels are stacked?

If someone could lend a helping hand, that'd be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked that the events are assigned to methods in the properties editor?

Comment: You are subscribed to the events for this methods?

Comment: @OlivierRogier What do you mean?

Comment: Does your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) hit the code? (btw; atm you change the font/color for the whole rtb; if something is selected you should change only the selection!!)))

Comment: @user11633402 [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events) => Instead of double clicking on an event, you can drop down a list of available events and select one. Use that to reassign lost events.